# composing (?) high order functions with javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm using high-order-functions to isolate some logic that shouldn't live my main handler function logic, this works nice but it's becoming a bit ugly and hard to keep chaining, I'm also not sure how to handle arity:

```
export const handler = sqsEvent(tryCaptureThrow(myHandler))
```

In this example, I have 2 HoFs: `sqsEvent` and `tryCaptureThrow`, both receive a fn and return a function. 
`tryCaptureThrow` for instance:

```
import { captureException } from '../utils/exception'

const tryCaptureThrow = (fn: any) => async (whatever: any) => {
  try {
    return await fn(whatever)
  } catch (e) {
    await captureException(e)
    throw e
  }
}

export default tryCaptureThrow
```

And this is how sqsEvent looks like:

```
import { SQSEvent } from 'aws-lambda'

import { captureException } from '../utils/exception'

const sqsEvent = (fn: any) => async (event: SQSEvent) => {
  try {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body)
    return fn(body)
  } catch (e) {
    await captureException(e, { event })
    return 'NOT-OK'
  }
}

export default sqsEvent
```

There are two things that I'd like to improve:

1) The amount of arguments the fn takes should be implicit - currently coded as a single one defined as `whatever`

2) Chaining more HoF should be simpler than wrapping the previous fn like it's currently happening.

I was trying to accomplish both using ramda, so it would look something like:

```
export const handler = R.someMethod(sqsEvent, tryCaptureThrow, myHandler)
```

It that possible? What's the method I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't have time to investigate right now, but do take a look at [`R.pipeWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeWith) or [`R.composeWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#composeWith).  They might possibly be of help.

Answer (score 0):

> The amount of arguments the `fn` takes should be implicit - currently coded as a single one defined as `whatever`

You could use rest parameters and spread syntax for this:

```
const tryCaptureThrow = (fn: any) => async (...args) => {
  try {
    return await fn(...args)
  } catch (e) {
    await captureException(e)
    throw e
  }
}
```

However, varargs are not totally functional, as types are getting more complicated with them. Having your function work only on unary `fn`s is fine.

> Chaining more HoF should be simpler than wrapping the previous `fn` like it's currently happening.

You're not doing any chaining or function composition here. It's even point-free.

It really doesn't get any simpler than simply calling the higher-order functions on the target.